# Django ReverseMatch error

Tags: django

Hi I can't figure this one out. I have in my application urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from journal import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
...     
url(r'^search/$', views.journal_search, name='journal_search'), 
...
)
```

in my views:

```
def journal_search(request):
if 'q' in request.POST:
    # search code
    ....
return render_to_response('journal_search_results.html',
            locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in the base.html:

```
{% load i18n %}
<form id="searchform" action="{% url journal_search %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}<fieldset class="search">
    <label for="search"></label> <input id="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="{% trans 'Search' %}... ">
</fieldset>
```

Any idea why I am getting:

```
 Reverse for 'journal_search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

? Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run the following in your shell? Any errors?

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
reverse('journal.views.journal_search')
```

If it works in the shell, it might not actually be a problem with the reverse.

Comment: I see. Sometimes, it's something else in the template that is causing the error, which is confusing. Any idea what it could be? Do you want to show some of your 'base.html' template?